# Site Template with Metadata SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, metadata, template

We are trying to clone a SharePoint 2013 web using templates, but the choice field information is not being included. Microsoft Docs states that taxonomy field info is by default not included with site templates. How can we include this metadata in a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is a limitation when saving a site as template. As a workaround, I suggest you use JavaScript Object model to copy taxonomy fields' values from the source list on the source site to the target list on the target site/site collection.

A blog for your reference:
[Copy taxonomy field values using javascript object model in Sharepoint](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2015/12/copy-taxonomy-field-values-using.html)